# How to create an _id sequence for a document and its array elements so that the array elements uniqueness is maintained across documents

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I would like to create and maintain book_id that is unique across different customer documents. For example. if customer_id is 1, then book_id should be 11,12,13,14 (the first digit of book_id denotes the customer_id) or any other pattern that would help track the customer_id using book_id.

```
  {
    "customer_id": "",
    "books": [
        { "book_id": "",
          ... }
    ]
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve this using MongoDB's auto-generated ID feature?

Comment: Have you considered using the `_id` field as a prefix for all of your `book_id`. Each document stored in Mongodb has a unique, indexed [_id](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#:~:text=In%20MongoDB%2C%20each%20document%20stored,update%20operations%20with%20upsert%3A%20true.) field (unless you overwrite it with your own implementation or disable it of course) which defaults to an ObjectId. You could concatenate that for example [`650ddc44507561a33ce927a1-11`, `650ddc44507561a33ce927a1-12`, `650ddc44507561a33ce927a1-13`]. Otherwise just create an ObjectId for each `book_id`.